# How to add an extra column including tab name when merging multiple sheets in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to merge multiple tabs into one master sheet. This is working fine:

=QUERY({SheetOne!A16:B;SheetTwo!A16:B;SheetThree!A16:B;SheetFour!A16:B}, "SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL", 0)

And it gives me the table

```
Week,Users
12,123
13,234
14,345
12,123
13,234
14,345
12,123
13,234
14,345
```

However, I'd like another column that creates a reference to the sheet. So the result I'd like is:

```
SheetName, Week, Users
SheetOne,12,123
SheetOne,13,234
SheetOne,14,345
SheetTwo,12,123
SheetTwo,13,234
SheetTwo,14,345
SheetThree,12,123
SheetThree,13,234
SheetThree,14,345
```

Thanks. Bonus question: How to insert a custom string-value instead of  SheetOne,SheetTwo [...]

Comment: What is gas? Not referring to gasoline i suppose.

Comment: Ah. Of course. Better start reading then.